# Modular addition in python

Tags: python, math, modular

I want to add a number y to x, but have x wrap around to remain between zero and 48. Note y could be negative but will never have a magnitude greater than 48. Is there a better way of doing this than:

```
x = x + y
if x >= 48:
    x = x - 48
elif x < 0:
    x = x + 48
```

?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
x = (x + y) % 48
```

The modulo operator is your friend.

```
>>> 48 % 48
0: 0
>>> 49 % 48
1: 1
>>> -1 % 48
2: 47
>>> -12 % 48
3: 36
>>> 0 % 48
4: 0
>>> 12 % 48
5: 12
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing modular arithmetic, you simply need to use the modulo operator.

```
x = (x + y) % 48
```

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't just `(x+ y)% 48` be suitable for you. See more on modulo [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 2):

you can use the modulo operator:

```
x = (x+y) % 48
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use

```
x = (x+y) % 48
```

which will give you positive `x` for any numbers.

Comment: Nonnegative x (could be 0).

Answer (score 1):

(x + y) % 48

Replace 48 with whatever you please.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make a class to handle modular arithmetic, like have been done here:
http://anh.cs.luc.edu/331/code/mod_arith.py
http://anh.cs.luc.edu/331/code/mod.py

Answer (score 0):

You may need the result of the division besides the remainder modulo n, so here's a seconds-to-year+days+etc translator which demonstrates the divmod function. Of course, one could go on to lustrum, decades, scores, century, or use fortnight or such. ;)

```py
nsec = 1989550000
mnt2sec = 60; hrs2mnt=60; day2hrs=24; yrs2day=365
mnt, dus = divmod(nsec, mnt2sec)
hrs, dum = divmod(mnt, hrs2mnt)
dys, duh = divmod(hrs, day2hrs)
yrs, dud = divmod(dys, yrs2day)
print(f'{nsec} s = {yrs} y, {dud} d, {duh} h, {dum} m, {dus} s')
# check
asec = (dus+mnt2sec*(dum+hrs2mnt*(duh+day2hrs*(dud+yrs*yrs2day))))
assert asec == nsec, "wrong sum rule"
```